# How to Backup to Azure Storage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, azure, azure-blob-storage

A day before I tried to back up our ddbb log file to azure storage. So, the transact is simple

```
backup [log|database] <name>
To URL = <Azure_Storage_url>
```

Credentials are defined apart,

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <Key>

CREATE CREDENTIAL <name_credentials>
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'
    ,SECRET   = <SAS_Token>
go
```

I got the error below:

```
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Cannot open backup device <Azure_Storage_url>. Operating system error 50(The request is not supported.).
```

I tested that credentials with a bulk insert on the same container I was pointing with  it works fine.

The SAS token was generated with full permissions

[image]

No policy were made on the container since I understood (Is my fault here?) that SAS token already had full access.

How can I do a successful backup from scratch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> No policy were made on the container since I understood (Is my fault here?) that SAS token already had full access.

Backup to URL requires a SAS Token generated from a Container Access Policy with fixed start and Expiration Dates.  An Storage Account-scoped SAS token will not work.